How to avoid calculating fields twice in mariadb view
I have following view in mariadb which gives stock credit, debit and balance :
SELECT pitem,
    Bdate,
    credit,
    debit, 
    sum(ifnull(bal, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY pitem ORDER BY bdate, DESC1) balance, 
    DESC1
FROM (
    SELECT a.Pitem,
        a.Bdate,
        a.Trn,
        If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0) AS Credit,
        If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0) AS Debit,
        (If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0)) - (If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0)) AS Bal,
        a.Desc1
    FROM (
        SELECT tblphmrefill.RfItem AS PItem,
            tblphmrefill.rfDate AS BDate,
            tblphmrefill.rfQty AS Qty,
            CONCAT(
                if(rfqty>0, 'Purchase No_', 'Discard_BMW_'), 
                coalesce(tblphmrefill.RfInvoice, 0), '_Vend_', rfsuppID
            ) AS DESC1,
            1 AS Trn
        FROM tblphmrefill
        UNION (
            SELECT invoicerefundphm.phmItem AS pItem,
                invoice.Bdate,
                invoicerefundphm.Qty,
                CONCAT('Refund_', billno, '_', invoice.BName) AS DESC1,
                1 AS Trn
            FROM invoice
        )
        INNER JOIN invoicerefundphm 
        ON invoice.BilID = invoicerefundphm.Billno
        UNION (
            SELECT invoicephm.phmItem AS PItem,
                invoice.BDate,
                invoicephm.Qty,
                CONCAT('Sales_', billno, '_', invoice.BName),
                0 AS Trn
            FROM invoicephm
            INNER JOIN invoice 
            ON invoicephm.Billno = invoice.BilID 
            ORDER BY invoice.bdate, invoice.bilid ASC
        )
    ) AS a 
) phmtbatch_int 
Order by Bdate, DESC1 Asc 

The problem is this part :
SELECT a.Pitem,
   a.Bdate,
   a.Trn,
   If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0) AS Credit,
   If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0) AS Debit,
   (If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0)) - (If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0)) AS Bal,
   a.Desc1

here the code is calculating balance but running the same calculation twice.
I have tried following thinng:
SELECT a.Pitem,
     a.Bdate,
     a.Trn,
     @Credit := (If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0)) AS Credit,
     @Debit := (If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0)) AS Debit,
     (@Credit - @Debit) AS Bal,
     a.Desc1

But mariadb throws an error 1351 saying
view contains variable or parameter which is not allowed

Is there any way to avoid calculating credit, debit twice for balance?

If your server  version supports CTE (10.2.2 or above) then use it. From the other side these are scalar calculations which are fast enough. PS. Also in (.. UNION .. UNION ..) use UNION DISTINCT as the last operator and UNION ALL as all above ones which will improve due to sortings amount decreased.

Be aware (also for similar cases in the future) of a problem that has caused LOTS of bugs in the world (because it sometimes can take months before it pops up): that the order of evaluation and assignments of @variables is undefined in MySQL, so you have no guarantee that the definition of @Credit is executed before its use! It probably will be... until it won't...

SELECT a.Pitem,
   a.Bdate,
   a.Trn,
   If((trn=1 AND a.qty>0), a.Qty, 0) AS Credit,
   If(trn=0 OR a.qty<0, abs(a.Qty), 0) AS Debit,
   (SELECT Credit - Debit) AS Bal,
   a.Desc1


Does this really work?  Credit should not be available until GROUP BY, HAVING, and ORDER BY.

@RickJames Not standard but it works with mysql/mariadb

Clever kludge!  Probably should test how much faster it actually is.

I'd guess it is not measurably faster than just having a third If, though maybe measurably slower.
